# Can AWS Step functions have Multiple Nested Workflows as a child (i.e. Parent having multiple childs)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I want to create multiple step functions which can be invoke by parent workflow. 
Explanation : I have Parent workflow and i want to invoke more than one step functions from that parent task state whenever i want to invoke, which is depends on a request from API gateway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - AWS Step Functions supports [nested workflows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-nested-workflows.html).

It's implemented as a Step Functions service integration in a Task state. The Step Functions service integration supports all three [service integration patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html):

- [Request Response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-default)
- [Run a Job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-sync) (synchronous invocation)
- [Wait for a Callback with the Task Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token)

Comment: Thanks Rob, but this supports only one nested step function invocation. Where in my case I need to invoke multiple step function in a single task state of step function. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean the [Parallel State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html)?

Comment: @ShrikantLahane I would suspect what you are looking for is execution of state machines from map states. However this is not supported by Step functions.

How did you end up solving this ?

Comment: @pinglocalhost As of today, step function does support nested stepfunction workflows within a map state allowing you to start stepfunctions concurrently